# Replicate and expand a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists `a` and `b` of the same length. And another list `a2` which contains all elements from `a` and some others. Now I want to construct a list `b2` so that for the shared elements between `a2` and `a`, the corresponding elements in `b2` and `b` are the same, and for those elements in `a2` but not `a`, the values in `b2` should be placeholder `0`.

Example:

```
a = {1, 2, 5, 8};
b = {10, 20, 50, 80};
a2 = {1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9};
(*Output b2={10,20,0,50,80,0}*)
```

I know how to achieve this in C-like languages, so I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this in Mathematica. Thanks!

P.S. `a` and `a2` are both ordered. And no duplicate exsists in either list, if it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all versions:

```
Replace[a2, Append[Thread[a -> b], _ -> 0], 1]
```

> ```
> {10, 20, 0, 50, 80, 0}
> ```

If you need speed look at [`Dispatch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dispatch.html).

For versions 10.0 or later Association functionality is fast and concise:

```
Lookup[AssociationThread[a, b], a2, 0]
```

> ```
> {10, 20, 0, 50, 80, 0}
> ```

Tersely `Thread` works in place of `AssociationThread` but it causes a redundant evaluation:

```
Lookup[Thread[a -> b], a2, 0]
```

> ```
> {10, 20, 0, 50, 80, 0}
> ```

Comment: Waw, nice to see you back  and to see such nice answer. Man when are finishing your book!

Answer (score 3):

```
Fold[Insert[#1, 0, #2] &, b, Position[Map[Position[a, #] &, a2], {}]]
```

> {10, 20, 0, 50, 80, 0}

Probably faster with large lists:

```
Fold[Insert[#1, 0, #2] &, b, Position[a2, Alternatives @@ Complement[a2, a]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious :

```
If[MemberQ[a, #], b[[Position[a, #][[1, 1]]]], 0] & /@ a2
```

> {10, 20, 0, 50, 80, 0}

Answer (score 2):

Some pure "mathematical" ad hoc:

```
a2 /. Thread[a -> b] /. Thread[Complement[a2, a] -> 0]
```

> {10, 20, 0, 50, 80, 0}

Answer (score 1):

```
mia = MapIndexed[Rule[#2, t[#1]] &, a];
mib = MapIndexed[Rule[#2, #1] &, b];
mic = MapIndexed[Rule[t[#1], #2] &, a2];
Normal@SparseArray[mib /. (mia /. mic), Length[a2]]
(*{10, 20, 0, 50, 80, 0}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 b2 = Sort[Join[{#, 0} & /@ Complement[a2, a], Join[Partition[Riffle[a, b], 2]]]][[All, 2]]
```

> {10, 20, 0, 50, 80, 0}