# Easiest/most efficient way to delete duplicates from one list at the positions of another?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, filtering

This question is somewhat related to [How to efficiently find positions of duplicates?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21341/how-to-efficiently-find-positions-of-duplicates) , although I'm interested in something a little bit simpler since I'm not really interested in a list of all the positions of duplicates in a list. I just want to delete duplicates of a given list based on the duplicates of another list.

As a simple example, let's say I have one list

```
myList = {1,3,1,2};
```

I perform some operations on this list, which yields a different list, but preserves the length

```
myNewList = {7,2,2,2};
```

After deleting duplicates, this list now becomes

```
myNewListReduced = {7,2};
```

Now, I would like to remove elements from my original list wherever the duplicates occurred in the new list. I do not necessarily care which of the positions are removed. In `myNewList`, the duplicates occurred at positions `2,3` and `4`. I would like to delete elements in my original list corresponding to that definition of duplicates, so that the following are all acceptable:

```
myListDuplicatesDeleted = {1,3};

myListDuplicatesDeleted = {1,1};

myListDuplicatesDeleted = {1,2};
```

That is, `3,1` and `2` from `myList` are all considered duplicates.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 15):

You can accomplish this using [`DeleteDuplicatesBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicatesBy.html), by first taking your two input lists and making a matrix out of them, and then deleting the rows where the last element (the element that came from `myNewList`) is a duplicate.  Then you transpose back and assign the sublists of the reduced matrix to the new lists you want.

```
{myListDuplicatesDeleted, myNewListReduced} = 
 Transpose@DeleteDuplicatesBy[Transpose@{myList, myNewList}, Last]
(* {{1, 3}, {7, 2}} *)
```

Or, slightly shorter and only returning the `myListDuplicatesDeleted` list,

```
First /@ DeleteDuplicatesBy[Transpose@{myList, myNewList}, Last]
```

And why not have yet another option to do this, we can use `GatherBy`.  I'm writing this in two equivalent ways to further confusion - the first uses `Part`, which I always prefer, and the second uses `First`, which people use a lot.

```
GatherBy[Transpose@{myList, myNewList}, Last][[All, 1, 1]]
Map[First, GatherBy[Transpose@{myList, myNewList}, Last], 2]
```

Comparing the available methods,

```
First /@ DeleteDuplicatesBy[Transpose@{myList, myNewList}, 
   Last] // RepeatedTiming
Map[First, GatherBy[Transpose@{myList, myNewList}, Last], 
  2] // RepeatedTiming

(* method by garej *)
Lookup[Thread[myNewList -> myList], 
  DeleteDuplicates@myNewList] // RepeatedTiming

(* method by Kuba *)
Module[{f}, f[x_] := (f[x] = 0; 1); 
  Pick[myList, f /@ myNewList, 1]] // RepeatedTiming

(* method by Hubble07 *)
Module[{dups = DeleteDuplicates[myNewList], pos},
   pos = Flatten[
     First@Position[myNewList, dups[[#]]] & /@ Range[Length[dups]]];
   myList[[pos]]
   ]; // RepeatedTiming


(* {0.0000131, {1, 3}} *)
(* {5.7*10^-6, {1, 3}} *)
(* {2.6*10^-6, {1, 3}} *)
(* {0.00001488, {1, 3}} *)
(* {0.0000192, {1, 3}}  *)
```

It appears that garej's method is the fastest (I still don't really understand it, but I have a blind spot for associations).  But for a list this size they are all pretty equivalent, what about for a much larger list?  Let's look at the timing for the `GatherBy` and `Lookup` methods for a couple of cases.  First, we have a large number of elements (100,000) in both lists, but only 200 unique elements in the `myNewList`.  In this case, the `Lookup` method is still faster (by 30%)

```
myList = Range[100000];
myNewList = RandomInteger[200, 100000];

Map[First, GatherBy[Transpose@{myList, myNewList}, Last], 
   2]; // RepeatedTiming

Lookup[Thread[myNewList -> myList], 
   DeleteDuplicates@myNewList]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0537, Null} *)
(* {0.038, Null} *)
```

But what if we had just as many elements, but now we have far more unique elements in `myNewList`.  In this case, the cost of using `Lookup` comes into play,

```
myList = Range[100000];
myNewList = RandomInteger[50000, 100000];

Map[First, GatherBy[Transpose@{myList, myNewList}, Last], 
   2]; // RepeatedTiming

Lookup[Thread[myNewList -> myList], 
   DeleteDuplicates@myNewList]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.11, Null} *)
(* {12.6, Null} *)
```

For this case, with a large list and many unique elements, Kuba's `Pick` method scales nearly as well as the `GatherBy` method, while Hubble07's straightforward method scales poorly.

**Edit**
The fastest method for doing this on a large list is garej's `AssociationThread` method, which when applied to the above large list gives

```
Values@
   AssociationThread[myNewList -> myList]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.031, Null} *)
```

This method fulfills the OP's requirements, but goes about it  <s>in an unintuitive way</s> by keeping the *last* association rather than the *first*.  Consider these two lists,

```
myList = Range[10]
myNewList = Range[5, 7]~Join~Range[7]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)
(* {5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} *)
```

and the two new lists that can be made from these lists

```
myList = Range[10]
myNewList = Range[5, 7]~Join~Range[7]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)
(* {5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} *)

Map[First, GatherBy[Transpose@{myList, myNewList}, Last], 2]
Values@AssociationThread[myNewList -> myList]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} *)
(* {8, 9, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7} *)
```

So for the value 5 which was duplicated in the `myNewList`, the `AssociationThread` method keeps the 8 from `myList` instead of the 1, which all the other methods pick.  This is fine and fits the requirements.  But while `AssociationThread` picks the correct elements to keep, it also **changes their order**, which may or may not be acceptable.

Comment: there is another option: `Values@AssociationThread[myNewList -> myList]`

Comment: @garej, That one takes the cake timewise.  For a larger list, it's hard to see how it chooses *which* of the elements in `myList` to keep for the various duplicates, but I think it does it correctly.  All the other methods choose the first corresponding entry, making it easy to check visually on a small list that it did the right thing.  I can add it here, or you can add it to your answer, on a large list it's the fastest method.

Comment: @JasonB it always keeps the last one per key, isn't it? It's like `<|1 -> old, 1->new|>`.

Comment: @Kuba, that's it, the old one is replaced by the new one.

Comment: If order is important you can `Reverse` both the old and new lists, perform the operation, then `Reverse` the result, and you'll have the original order.

Answer (score 14):

Comparable to other results:

```
Lookup[Thread[myNewList -> myList], DeleteDuplicates@myNewList]
```

> {1,3}

Seems most appropriate (fast and concise) for the OP task (V.10):

```
Values@AssociationThread[myNewList -> myList]
```

> {1,2}

P.S. Learned the general idea from this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104098/24604) of Mr.Wizard.

---

**Addenum**: Some notes concerning speed.

@Mr.Wizard suggested to compare two methods (one may play with `k` - list length - and `0.27` - ratio described below - to see what is going on):

```
k = 10^6;
a = RandomReal[1, k];
b = Round[a*(k * 0.27)];

positionDuplicates[list_] := GatherBy[Range@Length@list, list[[#]] &]

Values @ AssociationThread[b -> a] // Length // RepeatedTiming
a [[positionDuplicates[b][[All, 1]]]] // Length // RepeatedTiming

(* {1.02, 263300} *)
(* {1.02, 263300} *)
```

It is interesting to see that it is **ratio of number of unique elements to list length** that is important. If the ratio is less than 0.27 (empirically) `GatherBy` on average three times faster. (It is demonstrated in Mr.Wizard's example with the ratio 0.03). But when the ratio is higher than 0.27 `Association` method on average performs a bit better.

Note also that toy OP example is a bit misleading in this sense: it seems to have high density of duplicates in absolute terms, but the above ratio is `0.5`. It would be nice to know the real case.
I also hope that these results are not pure artefact of my system.

Comment: I love the new method!  Using the automatic duplicate removal of associations is great.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thank you, your opinion is indispensable

Comment: My appreciation for your elegant and insightful coding is not diminished but I feel it necessary to assert that the method implied in the question is actually faster than any of the existing answers, including this one.   I posted an example as an answer below.  If you have a counterexample please include it here.

Comment: Nice analysis and rebuttal. :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
Module[{f}, f[x_] := (f[x] = 0; 1); Pick[myList, f /@ myNewList, 1]]
```

> ```
> {1, 3}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

I love the brevity and elegance of [garej](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/24604/garej)'s second method and I would probably Accept it for that reason if nothing else, were this my Question.  Nevertheless it seems that using [the position method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21344/121) referenced in the question is actually faster.

```
positionDuplicates[list_] := GatherBy[Range @ Length @ list, list[[#]] &]

a = RandomReal[1, 1*^6];
b = Round[30000*a];

Values @ AssociationThread[b -> a]     // Length // RepeatedTiming
a[[ positionDuplicates[b][[All, 1]] ]] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.215, 30001}
>
> {0.0777, 30001}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
dups = DeleteDuplicates[myNewList];
pos = Flatten[
 First@Position[myNewList, dups[[#]]] & /@ Range[Length[dups]]];
myList[[pos]]
```

> {1, 3}